# Aligning text with a image

Tags: html, css

everyone I am having trouble aligning the paragraphs with the images can someone helps me. This was a assignment for a class that is currently targeting flex boxes.
[image: A website I am making for class]

I am struggling with this assignment. I want the background color of the paragraphs to be the same length as the images, therefore allowing the paragraphs to become aligned with them. I am not sure why they are not aligning with the images because I made the paragraph the same length.

Note: if anyone attempts to fix my code. Make sure you include flex boxes because its apart of the assignment criteria.

**HTML**

```
  <body>
        <h1> MINECRAFT</h1>
        <h2> Interesting Facts about Minecraft!</h2>
    
    <section class="animals">
        <img src = "Images/Cat.jpg" >
        <img src="Images/Iron Golem.webp">
        <img src= "Images/Dog.jpg">
    </section>
    
    <section class="names">
            <h3> 
                Cat</h3>
            <h3> Iron Golem</h3>
            <h3>Wolf</h3>
        
    
    
    </section>
    
    <section class="info">
        <p> If your beloved cat happens to pass away they will respawn at the village you got it from.
            After all cats do have 9 lives.
        </p>
        <p>
            Iron Golem purpose is to protect the villagers from enemies. If you happen to attack the Iron
            Golem don't be suprise if they fight back!
        </p>
        <p>
            Once you tame them with a few bones, they will protect you with their life!
        </p>
    
    </section>
    
    </body>
    
    
    </html>
```

**Css**

```
img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}
h2, h1, h3{
    text-align: center;
}
.animals {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.names{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    text-align: center;
}
h3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 150px;
    padding-right: 150px;
}
.info{
    display: flex;
}

p{
    margin: 1em;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-left: 150px;
    padding-right: 150px ;
    background-color: yellow ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you were doing was in `animals` class you have property of `justify-content: space-evenly`. which is missing in `info` class.
so just change the .info class to

```
.info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

**Final code:**  (To understand the concept better i have added bg-color around images.)

```
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: black;
}
h2,
h1,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.animals {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.names {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
}
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-right: 150px;
}
.info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

p {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

The output looks like:

[image]